# Swift Error: EXC BAD INSTRUCTION code=EXCI386 for userid

Tags: swift, swift4

I am writing an app login page when I countered this error. I do not know how to debug it so I am asking where I coded wrong. I got a problem on the keychain wrapper code:
`KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.uid)!,forKey: "uid")`

I am following a YouTube tutorial on Swift 4, the most updated version. However, it seems this line of code has some problems, therefore I would like to know the problem in the whole code, whether I missed I bracket or failed to import.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseCore
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import FirebaseStorage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userimageview: UIImageView!

    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var selectedImage = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self    
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if KeychainWrapper.standard.object(forKey: "KEY_UID") != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
        }
    }

    func storeuserdata(userId: String) {
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.2) {
            Storage.storage().reference().putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                guard let metadata = metadata else {
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    return
                }
                // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL
                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId).setValue(["username": self.usernameField.text!,"userImg": downloadURL

                ])
            }   
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signinpressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil && (self.usernameField.text?.isEmpty)! && self.userimageview.image != nil {
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                    self.storeuserdata(userId: (user?.uid)!)

                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.uid)!,forKey: "uid")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
                }
            }else {
                KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.uid)!,forKey: "uid")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
                }            
            }
        }    
    }

    @IBAction func getPhoto (_ sender: AnyObject) {
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = image
        }
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and update your question with the exact error message.

Comment: You really need to spend time learning how to properly work with optionals in Swift. Every use of `!` in your code is a crash waiting to happen (not counting `!=` and in comments of course).